# How can I filter a query in Firebase to a specific field within a child of my posts? - Firebase & Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, sorting, firebase-realtime-database

I am tryin to filter my Firebase Database query results in to a specific result within a field of my childs but when I look at my debugger, the snapshot shows the whole dictionary no matter what I try.

This is my [Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6ytj.png), I want to filter out only those posts that have a "lostfound" = "lost"

This is the code that I've done so far and is not working..

```
func fetchLostPostsFirebase() {

    let database = Database.database()
    let databaseRef = database.reference()
    databaseRef.child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "lostfound").queryEqual(toValue: "lost").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
    }
}
```

The end result would be to use this as a way to sort posts into two collection views where I would populate the data I fetch. But I am not completely sure how to do it.I am am changing my project from Parse to Firebase and wanted to know how to filter the query to do an if else statement.

Comment: When you say the code is not working, can you update your question to describe what is happening and what the expected behavior is?

Comment: Done! I don't know much about Firebase, the thing is that in Parse I did this --- queryfound.whereKey("lostfound", equalTo: "found") -- to then grab the data and populate it in my collection view but now I'm all confused with Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to use .observe(.value) instead of .observer(.childAdded)

Comment: and how would I sort the query then? For example if i wanted to sort the firebase posts based on if inside a post, the post is "lost" or a "found"?. How would I sort that value from the snapshot.